# Configure apache for system passwords?

Tags: apache, configuration, authorization

I know I can use htpasswd to create a password file for apache, but how do I configure it to use valid users or groups from the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use an appropriate authentication module. Here's an example with `mod_authnz_external`: http://blog.innerewut.de/2007/6/26/apache-2-2-authentication-with-mod_authnz_external